# Firewall security and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, security

I have been receiving messages in my log file saying :-

"Login failed for user 'sa': Reason Password did not match that for the login provided. [Client:xx.xx.xx.xx]"

the xx are actual numbers.

In the MS firewall, I've added my IP to the "Remote IP address" list on the Scope tab.

When I have gone back to the log file, the message has stopped appearing.  Instead it says "its starting up ReportServerTempDB", does this mean that I've inadvertently by adding my IP to the remote IP list allowed anyone in?

By putting only my IP address in the scope means I've blocked everyone else apart from me connecting to the remote database?

Ultimately, I would like remote access allowed only to my IP.  If that is not possible, I want a block on all remote access.

Comment: I meant "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By putting only my IP address in the scope means I've blocked everyone else apart from me connecting to the remote database?

Correct.

> Exceptions that you add to the firewall can restrict the opening of
>   the port to incoming connections from specific computers or the local
>   subnet. This restriction of the scope of the port opening can reduce
>   how much your computer is exposed to malicious users, and is
>   recommended.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/configure-the-windows-firewall-to-allow-sql-server-access?view=sql-server-ver15#BKMK_additional_settings

Comment: Thanks David.  I now get "Starting up ReportServerTempDB" message, that's nothing to worry about.  Its not caused by any external hack attempt?  The source is spidxxs.

Comment: Right.  Just a normal startup event.